# How to keep objects created inside other objects alive without using new?

Tags: c++, oop, dynamic-allocation

I am writing a game in C++, and I have come upon this design problem:

I have a base class called `Entity` for all my objects in the game. In order to use inheritance, I am storing the pointers in my `octree`. In my game, there are objects that will be created by other objects' methods. The problem is: where can I store the objects created this way so that it will stay for the duration of the game so that the pointers I store are valid?

I do not want to use `new` because I will create probably hundreds or even thousands of objects this way and I heard `new` is very slow.

The only way I have come up so far is to have a big vector that stores all these objects. The vector will probably be initialized with a huge size so that it won't have to resize itself and messes with my pointers. This seems rather dumb though.

Comment: *"This seems rather dumb though"* why exactly? Having a manager (of some sort) for all the Entities in a game is pretty common

Comment: Good luck with your project! I don't have specific advice other than a recommendation you have a look at http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/ - it talks about this kind of thing a bit.

Comment: I don't know how memory is handled in "big" games, but even for games you should not worry about performance *first*. First of all write good, readable, understandable, testable and **maintainable** code. Then you measure, benchmark and profile to find the bottlenecks and optimize those (with plenty of comments and documentation, as optimizations tend to make unreadable and unmaintainable code). And remember, good enough often *is* good enough.

Comment: @UnholySheep I think it is inelegant because the vector will do nothing except to keep my objects alive since I already have the octree managing my objects

Comment: If after profiling you find that memory allocations are indeed a bottleneck, there are many ways to implement your own memory allocation system, many freely available all over the Internet (either as finished open-source code, or documented with algorithms you can implement yourself).

Comment: Unless your target platform is a potato, allocating thousands of objects with `new` is absolutely fine, although I'd recommend using smart pointers that hide the messy memory management away from you.

Comment: If you are writing C++ in 2018, you should not be using `new`. Watch this [CppCon 2017 video by Herb Sutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE). It talks exactly about the situation that you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: don't worry too much about performance. Adhere to some basic rules for that and you'll be fine:

- avoid copies of big objects (pass by pointer or reference)
- prefer vector over map and set when you have < 50 entries, or do not need ordering
- have a look at what the std::algorithm library gives you - these functions are usually fast and tested

most important thing for your project is: think about structure and design

- use clear interfaces
- have single responsibility of objects
- prefer composition over inheritance

as for your concrete problem:
It's fine to have a "ObjectManager" class. as a first implementation a vector is fine, too, just hide that as a implementation detail so you can change it later on if the need arises.

Answer (score 0):

One way of improving the `new` is to define [custom allocators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_(C%2B%2B)#Custom_allocators) for your object,  that take advantage of knowledge about your classes to write a better new than the standard one.

The good news is that you can write your code immediately using `new` and later create your custom allocator. So don't get lost in the dangers of premature optimization, which is, we all know:

> Premature optimisation is the the root of all evil 
>   -- Donald Knuth

If `Entity` is the base class for all objects, I suppose that you'll make heavy use of polymorphism. Unfortunately, you can't manage easily polymorphic objects in vectors (which would be the more convenient and safer way) because of the [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) issue.  So pointer is ok in this case.  Maybe you could consider `shared_ptr` to avoid memory leaks.

This being said, you may be interested in [this article](https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/the-entity-component-system-c-game-design-pattern-part-1-r4803/) about Entity-Component-System pattern in games, and memory allocation.